# Redirect old browsers

Tags: php, redirect, browser

Is it possible to use the PHP get_browser() method to redirect browsers under a certain version?

Example:

Redirect All browsers below Internet Explorer 9, Safari 6, Chrome 26.0.1410.64, Opera 12, and Firefox 20.

The purpose of this is when a visitor comes to my site, I can either redirect them to a downgraded version(Which does not use HTML5, or CSS3) or I can give them a notice that an update is available(meaning I would have to update my code upon new releases).

Moreover I would rather redirect them to a downgraded version of my site but any help on getting version numbers would be great.

Thanks

I found this line of code doing a Google search, but I am so new to PHP I really do not know where to start to put this type of script together. :(

```
$using_ie6 = (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 6.') !== FALSE);
```

Comment: This is a bad thing to do. Instead check for specific things using something like http://modernizr.com/. For instance, if your site needs localStorage, canvas and flexbox, use Modernizr to check and then redirect away. Chances are that Chrome 20 is fine, as is Firefox 10.

Comment: 1) many of the HTML5 and CSS3 features you want will work just fine in older browsers; [check for features](http://modernizr.com/) not specific browsers. 2) many features that are missing can be simulated in old browsers using [Polyfill scripts](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills). 3) browser detection is notoriously unreliable, especially in server-side code -- use it at your peril. 4) If you can't polyfill, consider using [progressive enhancement](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) rather than browser blocking.

Comment: But would it also not be a good practice to at least let a user know that their browser is out of date?

Comment: This is a frontend issue, not backend. Feature detection by user agent is ineffective sometimes, considering that user agents not always are browsers. Prefer progressive enhancement with Modernizr.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to vist your website with older browser, you should create a index file before user visit your website.

like this structure:

```
- root
-- index.php
-- yourWebsiteFolder
--- website files ...
```

in index.php you can check the user browser with this code:

```
$browsers = "mozilla msie gecko firefox ";
$browsers.= "konqueror safari netscape navigator ";
$browsers.= "opera mosaic lynx amaya omniweb maxthon theworld traveler chrome";
$browsers = explode(" ", $browsers);
$nua = strToLower( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$l = strlen($nua);
for ($i=0; $i<count($browsers); $i++){
      $browser = $browsers[$i];
      $n = stristr($nua, $browser);
      if(strlen($n)>0){
            $GLOBALS["ver"] = "";
            $GLOBALS["nav"] = $browser;
            $j=strpos($nua, $GLOBALS["nav"])+$n+strlen($GLOBALS["nav"])+1;
            for (; $j<=$l; $j++){
                  $s = substr ($nua, $j, 1);
                  if(is_numeric($GLOBALS["ver"].$s) )
                      $GLOBALS["ver"] .= $s;
                  else
                      break;
            }
      }
}

if( ($GLOBALS["nav"] == "firefox" && $GLOBALS["ver"] <= 15) || ( $GLOBALS["nav"] == "msie" && $GLOBALS["ver"] <= 8 ) ) {
    // browser is older
}
else
{
    // go to website
    header("location: yourWebsiteFolder");
}
```

in this code, if user's browser was firefox version 15 or less, Or was IE version 8 or less you can print your error message, else user can visit your website.

Comment: Testing your code I get this error Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in D:\wamp\www\Template\index.php on line 23

Comment: that's no problem. you can use function `explode()` Instead of `split()`. so now, your edited line is `$browsers = explode(" ", $browsers);`.

Answer (score -2):

This might not the answer you are looking for, but:

**Don't do this!**

- Browser detection on the server side never has been reliable.
- If search engines find out that you deliver different content to visitors you will get punished sooner or later.

**Instead:** (most of this has been mentioned in the comments)

- Detect features you use, not browsers. Do on the client side.
- Check if features you need could some how be done with some JavaScript that you inject in case the feature is not available.
- If a feature is not available and could not be emulated show a small message or, in case for the most CSS3 issues, ignore them somehow. (Example: If a browser does not support CSS3 transisition, this is fine in the most use cases. Older browsers do not show the animation, but displayed end result will be the same.)

To generalise: HTML5 is not some super cool all new markup. It is mostly just some new tags and their default behavior could be displayed in older browsers.
Most of the new CSS3 stuff is some very helpful eyecandy, but nothing more. Example: No CSS3 gradients - no problems. Use a plain color or "old school" images for browser which don't support this.

Again, as said in the comments [modenizr](http://modernizr.com/) is a good place to start.